# Edge and Chrome flag pyinstaller as a virus

Tags: pyinstaller, nuitka

I created a simple python script to fetch crypto currency prices from website and then saves them to a csv file, the script works fine and flawlessly but when I compile the script and try to send it to someone or just create a release on GitHub it gets flagged as a virus when downloaded in edge and chrome but not brave (didn't test for Firefox) I tried compiling with `pyinstaller` of different versions 3.6 and the latest release I even tried to compile it myself by downloading the source code from github but it just keeps on getting flagged as virus, then I tried pyarmor-webui and changed some settings I know it uses `pyinstaller` but I though changing the settings will help but I was wrong

I tried `nuikta` with different settings but I keep on getting the same result

I followed [this](https://python.plainenglish.io/pyinstaller-exe-false-positive-trojan-virus-resolved-b33842bd3184) writeup but still not successful

I also tried changing the executable metadata with resource hacker and that didn't seem to help

I even tried to test with a simple hello world script and still got the same result
how do you fix this

```
import random 

print ("Hello world!")

for i in range(3):
    print (random.randrange(0,9))
```